# cURL not working - show PHP the files in PHP directory - NOT Windows configuration

Tags: php, curl

- I'm running Windows 10 x64 and the latest version of PHP 7.
- I have removed the semicolon from `extension=php_openssl.dll` in the `php.ini` file.
- The file `PHP\ext\php_curl.dll` exists.
- The files `PHP\libeay32.dll` and `PHP\ssleay32.dll` exist.
- I know I need to restart the HTTP server for PHP to see the files after I do the last step.

I explicitly do *not* want to dump the files in to a Windows directory as I routinely reinstall Windows and I simply migrate everything as portable between OS installs with zero negative effects.

How do I update PHP to see the files in *it's own directory*?

Comment: have you checked which path extension_dir points to in php.ini?

Comment: @Bizoon I moved the two files there, updated the Apache configuration and restarted, no dice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded a slightly newer version of PHP, *that* didn't work.

Then I downloaded a newer version of Apache, migrated the older settings and *that* worked. This is the only relevant `httpd.conf` settings I've changed:

```
LoadFile "C:/WAMP/Apache/bin/libeay32.dll"
LoadFile "C:/WAMP/Apache/bin/libssh2.dll"
LoadFile "C:/WAMP/Apache/bin/ssleay32.dll"
```